# Will the integrated GPU be enough

Tags: integrated-graphics

I've seen [this](https://superuser.com/questions/228563/should-i-get-integrated-graphics-if-i-already-have-a-dedicated-gpu) question, but the answers are tainted by the asker already having a graphics card to put in.

I'm looking at pairing a Sandybridge i5 2500K with an Intel H67 chipset board(already got a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/264787/running-a-sandybridge-i5-2500k-on-an-h67-board) asking if anyone knows of problems with that pairing*) , the rig will be used to power dual 24 inch monitors but the main usage is going to be development and general use, not gaming.

These monitors will be running with a resolution of 1920 x 1080

I found [this](http://www.anandtech.com/show/3871/the-sandy-bridge-preview-three-wins-in-a-row/7) via a link in another question, it has some very pretty graphs, but unfortunately they don't mean much to me.

Will the integrated graphics provide enough power?

- If the community feels these 2 questions are too similar I'll delete or rephrase as appropriate.

Comment: What's the resolution of the monitors?

Comment: @AndrejaKo I've edited the question to include the info, but they will be running at 1920 x 1080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be more than adequate for displaying general use things like text documents, emails, spreadsheets, and webpages. (By comparison, I think these are an order of magnitude faster than USB->DVI external video adapters and THOSE display full HD monitors just fine.)  Resolution isn't actually that important when you're just doing static rendering.  You might possibly run into trouble with, say, real-time graphs of the stock market, because that's some heavy 2D drawing, but even then my hunch is you'd be fine, with at worst some barely-noticeable hiccups.

I wouldn't count on it running Crysis too well, though, but you don't seem concerned about that.

Answer (score 2):

U used a netbook with Atom N550 to drive a monitor running at 1920x1200 and the netbook's screen running at 800x600 and didn't have any problems at all for text work and development.

If my sources are correct, i5 should have better integrated GPU. I can't tell if it will run monitors nicely on your setup, but I'd expect it to run a two monitors at 1920x1200 with no problems.